# How to fix laravel migrate receiving "Curl error (code 3): <url> malformed"?

Tags: laravel-5

I just pulled some updates in a repository. Then when I use the command "php artisan migrate" it gives me an error. See the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Or what seems to be causing this?

Thank you!

**Edit**

Heres the code for Util.php. But I don't think I should be messing with it since it came from vendors directory.

```
<?php
```

namespace Monolog\Handler\Curl;

class Util
{
    private static $retriableErrorCodes = array(

```
    CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST,

    CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT,

    CURLE_HTTP_NOT_FOUND,

    CURLE_READ_ERROR,

    CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED,

    CURLE_HTTP_POST_ERROR,

    CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR,

);

public static function execute($ch, $retries = 5, $closeAfterDone = true)
{
    while ($retries--) {
        if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
            $curlErrno = curl_errno($ch);

            if (false === in_array($curlErrno, self::$retriableErrorCodes, true) || !$retries) {
                $curlError = curl_error($ch);

                if ($closeAfterDone) {
                    curl_close($ch);
                }

                throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Curl error (code %s): %s', $curlErrno, $curlError));
            }

            continue;
        }

        if ($closeAfterDone) {
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722822/guzzle-returns-curl-error-3-url-malformed

Comment: @PoojaJadav I've already read that question, but I'm not using Guzzle.

Comment: Try this [curl-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718111/laravel-logging-to-slack-workbook-causes-curl-error-code-3-url-malformed)

Comment: can you paste the code around line 45 on Util.php

Comment: @ColinMD Check my edit

Comment: The error is coming from this file, check the excpetion 'throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Curl error (code %s): %s', $curlErrno, $curlError));'  Now you just need to figure what is firing this method

Comment: Are you using slack or any other external logger for notifications? And if so have you setup your config correctly?

Comment: @ColinMD No I'm not using slack, does telescope count as external logger?

Comment: Just enter this in the code in this place public static function execute($ch, $retries = 5, $closeAfterDone = true)
{
    dd($ch);
    while ($retries--) { and paste the results

Comment: @ColinMD It's trying to migrate a specific file that doesn't exist anymore. After that the error shows.

Comment: Yeah you must have some logging setup incorrectly. Monolog is the error handler and if its using CURL then its trying to communicate with an external service, you just need to figure out what that service is, and the issue is generally URL is blank or incorrect

Comment: If you put the code in I sent it will hopefully give you the url it is trying to communicate with

Comment: Is it a live system? or in a test environment?

Comment: @ColinMD It's a test environment.

Comment: @ColinMD The url  returns blank

Comment: Ok add dd($ch); just before the while statement and paste the results

Comment: Ok, can you paste the parts of your .env file that do not contain sensitive information and the contents of your logging.php config file

Comment: @ColinMD curl resource {@755
  url: ""
  content_type: null
  http_code: 0
  header_size: 0
  request_size: 0
  filetime: -1
  ssl_verify_result: 0
  redirect_count: 0
  total_time: 0.0
  namelookup_time: 0.0
  connect_time: 0.0
  pretransfer_time: 0.0
  size_upload: 0.0
  size_download: 0.0
  speed_download: 0.0
  speed_upload: 0.0
  download_content_length: -1.0
  upload_content_length: -1.0
  starttransfer_time: 0.0
  redirect_time: 0.0
  redirect_url: ""
  primary_ip: ""
  certinfo: []
  primary_port: 0
  local_ip: ""
  local_port: 0
}

Comment: @ColinMD I just checked logging.php and I just noticed there was a channel for slack that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Good stuff, glad its sorted.  You should now get the real error message

Answer (score 1):

Not a permanent fix, but rather than have this you can commented it out `throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Curl error (code %d): %s', $curlErrno, $curlError));` and the I had  `return true;`